# Why fine structure correction turn out to be not-defined in this case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, perturbation-theory, spectroscopy

As given in R. Shankar's Quantum Mechanics, The total fine structure energy shift
$$E^1_{\text{T.S}}=E^1_T+E^1_\text{S.O.}$$
$$E^1_{\text{T.S}}=-\frac{mc^2\alpha^2}{2n^2}\frac{\alpha^2}{n}\left(\frac{1}{j+1/2}-\frac{3}{2n}\right)\ \ \text{For both}\ j=l\pm 1/2$$

I'm trying to find out the splitting in case of $n=2$ So  $l=0,1$. Thus $j=\pm1/2,3/2,1/2$, But if take the case of $j=-1/2$, Clearly the above result give infinite. Why is that so??

---

The same problem is with Spin-orbit correction alone which is given by
$$E^1_\text{S.O.}=\frac{1}{4}mc^2\alpha^4\frac{1}{n^3(l)(l+1/2)(l+1)}\begin{Bmatrix}
l  \\
-(l+1) 
\end{Bmatrix} $$

Consider the case of $l=0$, clearly the denominator blows up. What's the flaw here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular momentum quantum numbers are always positive. Their projection might be negative. So $j\geq 0$, but $m_j = -j, -j+1, \cdots, j-1, j$.

The addition of $\ell$ and $s$ gives $j = |\ell-s|, |\ell-s+1|, \cdots, |\ell+s-1|, |\ell+s|$.

So for $\ell = 0$: 
$j = 0+1/2$ or $j = |0-1/2|$, so $j=1/2$.

For $\ell=1$: 
$j = 1-1/2=1/2$ or $j=1+1/2 = 3/2$.

Comment: How about the case of $l=0$ in the spin-orbit coupling case? Clearly $l$ can take $0$ value.

Comment: Also, I think, You did the typo as it should be $|l+s-1|,|l+s|$

Comment: @YoungKindaichi Yes thanks I fixed the typo. Yes $\ell$ can be zero, but $j$ can't since $s$ is always non-zero.